# GPO printer allocation

Tags: printer, active-directory

scenario:

AD domain with multiple remote OUs with fairly robust communications.  I allocate printers per location via GPO. Some of the Work Stations in the OU allocate the printers on login (5 of them) right alway, some 1 every 10-15 seconds, they pop up on the display and other do not.  My wmic command on the WS works but if I issue the command from my work station I get "no instance avaiable" I am researching that now.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393266(VS.85).aspx